# Images failing to load in IE with DOM: 7009 error (unable to decode) in console

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom

When loading many images on a single page in IE (reproduced in IE11), some of them begin to fail to load, and have something similar to the following warning in the console:

> DOM7009: Unable to decode image at URL: '[some unique url]'.

When I look at the network traffic, there does appear to valid responses received for each of these images from the server.  It's not always the same images each time.  If I use the dev tools to force the image to reload (example: I update the url to include some some extraneous url parameter "&test=1"), it loads/renders normally without error.  I've reproduced this behavior with different types of images (jpegs/pngs; example png included below).  It seems to happen more frequently as the number of images go up, and may also have some correlation with the size of each image.

Any thoughts as to what might be causing this?  Potential work-arounds?  Any help is appreciated.

[image: Sample PNG]

Comment: Can we see some of the images that give you this error? Are they dataURL images?

Comment: They are not, each one has a "src" attribute pointing to an endpoint exposed in our asp.net application.  Each image (and it's corresponding url) represents a specific page of a specific document.  The service does the work of converting the original content (in one of many formats) into a PNG to be sent to the browser.  I've added an example of one such PNG generated by our system above, although I'm not sure what additional compression SO/imgur will do to the image.

Comment: I've created a jsbin page to demonstrate this bug - http://jsbin.com/xegularomu.  However, this points to the same imgur link above, and I expect imgur would begin to throttle traffic if this was run very often.  I can consistently reproduce it in IE11 (usually starts to fail somewhere around 200 images)

Comment: I see these errors as well, with images loaded for FlexSlider. The all appear in the slider, though.

Comment: I'm seeing this same error in a WinJS application when only working with two images (and switching an <img> tag's src="" property).

Will keep you posted with anything I find.

Answer (score 36):

It looks like the actual problem is addressed in [another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33676983/13179). All of the answers here get around the issue in various ways, but this is likely happening because the file is not the format it claims to be. Because [nosniff](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2008/09/02/ie8-security-part-vi-beta-2-update/) is enabled, the browser is unable to work around this issue, and attempts to decode the wrong image type.

In other words: Your file extension does not match the actual encoding

Comment: Wow! Someone on this thread that actually has a valid answer for how to FIX rather than INSECURE workaround!  have your first upvote!

Comment: The bottom line is: always check the actual type files you're given! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem in a site hosted in IIS due the X-Content-Type-Options header being set in a parent applications web.config like this:

```
<system.webServer>   
 <httpProtocol>    
  <customHeaders>    
   <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />    
  </customHeaders>    
 </httpProtocol> 
</system.webServer>
```

Removing it in the applications web.config fixed it:

```
<remove name="X-Content-Type-Options" />
```

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem where a file was reported in the HTTP headers as a JPEG but was in fact a PNG. Changing the filetype to match the file or removing the "X-Content-Type-Options" header fixed the problem.

Comment: Had the same png/jpg mixup but instead of the headers it was the actual file ending that was wrong. Turns out Chrome allows foo.jpg to be called by using foo.png (and vice versa) and it will be displayed correctly, but IE (and possibly other browsers) doesn't allow it and hence won't find the image.

Answer (score 7):

The problem I was facing off was similar. I have a Java web application which shows pages and thumbnails of a document through Servlet requests, which responds to the browser sending PNG images. Like @user1069816 said, the responses were arriving with a header that was causing the problem "Unable to decode image":

```
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

In my case, this header were introduced by **Spring Security**. Besides this is a [security mechanism for Internet Explorer to avoid XSS attacks](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/headers.html#headers-content-type-options), the fastest solution to disable this header on response were putting the following line on the application context file of Spring Security, `headers` section:

```
<http use-expressions="true" create-session="never" auto-config="true">
    <headers>
        <!-- this section disable put the header 'X-Content-Type-Options' -->
        <content-type-options disabled="true"/>
    </headers>
```

This problem were only happening on Internet Explorer 11. Not in Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Is there is any other way to achieve the same. If we disable, it will disable the security.

Answer (score 6):

I've encountered this error as well — IE 11.0.9600.18059. According to my testing, it was almost certainly due to the amount of memory consumed by the tab (eg: adding extra DOM elements increases the memory usage) — not to be confused with the amount of data loaded over the network.

Using the memory profiler, I found that errors occurred once memory usage hit a ceiling around 1.5GB. This caused the following weirdness:

1. Some images would be loaded, but wouldn't render. They'd show up as an empty space in the page (with the correct dimensions), as though the image had been set to `visibility: hidden`.
2. Some images would be loaded, but would fail to decode. They'd show up as a small black box with an X. These images would also show a DOM7009 error in the console.
3. Flash SWFs would show up as black boxes.
4. Other random weirdness.

Different images/SWFs would be affected each time I reloaded the page.

The solution for me was to simply adjust the way the page is designed, so it's not causing IE to consume as much memory.

Answer (score 4):

If it's of any use I have been seeing this on my WinJS application and I believe it's a way of renderer reporting that it's out of memory (albeit cryptically!)

Reason I say that is that if I load an compressed `png` image which is say 500KB, but large in terms of pixel dimensions I get this problem.

**E.g.**

If I try this with a 20000 x 6000 image I get this error sporadically, which I'm guessing is because it's 20000 x 6000 x 4 (480,000,000 bytes) or ~480MB.

If I try this with a 14000 x 6000 it would be ~336MB which seems OK and I have yet to get the error.

If I try this with a 35000 x 20000 image ~2.8GB it always happens.

Answer (score 4):

Got the same issue in the IE11 when I load images it was giving me an error:

**`DOM7009: Unable to decode image at URL`**

In all other browsers, it works like a charm!!

After a bit of the research finally came on the conclusion as below:

in the Web.config file::

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="Deny" />
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
        <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1" />
        <!--To resolve the user image not displaying in the chat and in the header for IE 11--> 
        <!--<add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff"/>-->
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Please see the commented code I have removed the "**X-Content-Type-Options**" and it works!!!

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this same error on a page that was essentially an image gallery, where each image was being loaded at full resolution as the thumbnail. The page weight was approx 220mb. Some of the thumbnails weren't loading, and the "unable to decode image at url" error was being given as the reason.

However, IE could load up each image individually by viewing the image's URL directly, which I think means there wasn't a problem with the image type/encoding. So while IE11 could load up the individual image, it couldn't load up all the images as thumbnails (and the images that weren't loaded changed each time the page was refreshed).

My workaround was to display a low res thumbnail on the page (page weight changed to 220kb), and have the thumbnail link to the full, hi-res image.

It would be worth checking if you can reduce the dimensions of the images served, and also the file size.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem just now when the image was ~2.5MB (.jpg). Shrunk it down to 540kb and the problem no longer occurs. Looks like it's definitely an IE memory issue (or can be in some occasions).

This is the only fix that worked for me as I didn't have anything relating to `X-Content-Type-Options` in my web config.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I found to solve this is disable this rule by browser in apache server configuration.

```
 BrowserMatch MSIE explorer
 Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff env=!explorer
```

It work for me but this solution doesnt like me. I would prefer to rewrite in apache server the correct mime-type.

My problem is that the URL contains the "captcha" string, but I can`t set it.

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^(.*)captcha$ headerpng 
Header set "Content-type image/png" env=headerpng
```

This doesn`t work. It's a little frustrating. It's a url so long and I thing that **SetEnvIf** doesn`t read it until the end.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same issue frequently with IE11 and I can't pinpoint what is causing it.  However, it starts to happens right after JavaScript has crashed. I'ts not an imgur problem, its an IE11 problem.

The only way that I have been able to get out of the issue is to crash explorer and reload it or reboot.