# Internet explorer is not showing gif images

Tags: internet-explorer, gif

gif images are not being displayed in a webpage, but if I am saving the complete webpage(.jsp) on PC , files folder contains those pics

Comment: I am using IE 11

Comment: Do you have Tracking Protection turned on? Tools>Tracking Protection. Websites most of the time use images to track your surfing.

Comment: turned on, but it is still not working

Comment: Can you provide a link to the web page please. To list Blocked content on a web page first. Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "Always record developer console messages". On refreshing or opening the site, press f12 then select the console tab, it will now list any blocked content warnings, on the network tab of dev tools, you can inspect the response headers of your image resources.

Comment: still not working

Comment: Error:DOM7009: Unable to decode image at URL

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Internet Explorer DOM7009: Unable to decode image at URL: [url]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33676982/internet-explorer-dom7009-unable-to-decode-image-at-url-url)

tip: to research any computer error, copy and paste it into your web browsers' address bar and press enter..... the search results will include links to already answered questions or MSDN documentation about the error code. eg.

[Web search for "Error DOM7009 Unable to decode image at URL"](http://www.bing.com/search?q=Error%3ADOM7009%3A%20Unable%20to%20decode%20image%20at%20URL&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IESR02&pc=EUPP_)