# JPEG Images not loading in IE11 browser served through apache web server

Tags: apache, internet-explorer-11

I'm using apacher web server to stre the static content (like images, css etc.) with my website. Below is my apache configurations set :

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on
   <FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf|html)$">
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 30 minutes"
   </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch ".+\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf|html|woff)$">
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Please note that the same apache configuration is working in test region, but not working in prod region for same jpeg images.

The cache works well for woff,css, js,png files, but doesnt work for my few jpeg images which are loaded from specific folder for one of the website screen. Any idea why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPEG Images not loading in IE11 browser through apache web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57844016/jpeg-images-not-loading-in-ie11-browser-through-apache-web-server)

Comment: I make a simple test in my side and the jpeg images can load well in IE. I set up Apache 2.4 web server in my windows system and put my website in htdocs folder. Have you used F12 dev tools to debug the website in IE11 to see if there's any error? I think it could be better if you provide [your steps or a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce the issue. You could also refer to [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/274049/apache-tomcat-ie-caching-problem).

Comment: @Yu Zhou : I did check in dev tools, these jpeg images are loading properly without any issues. Please note that the same set of jpeg images are showing properly in producton server on website screen, where in test server these images are showing in website screen. When i tried to open images exclusively like this : https://<applhome>/common/App_Theme/Green/images/Prev_disabled.jpg, then its showing cross mark which is 304 error. Please check and provide feedback as i'm stuck with this issue for longtime.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is related with cache. 304 Not Modified means it loads the cache. It indicates that the requested resource has not been modified since the previous transmission, so there is no need to retransmit the requested resource to the client. You could try `Ctrl+F5` to hard refresh in IE to see if the picture shows.

In [this article](https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/304-not-modified), it says that *the `mod_cache` module is the most likely culprit for producing unexpected **304** codes in Apache. Thus, within the configuration file you have open look for a section that checks for the `mod_cache.c` file*. You could refer to the [official sample configuration](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_cache.html#sampleconf).

After finding this configuration, you could try to comment out the caching section by adding `#` characters at the start of every line to be commented out (but don't delete anything). Then save the modified configuration file then restart the Apache web server to see if this fixed the problem.

Comment: @Zhou :  There is no mod_cache section in the conf file. I tried Ctrl+F5 also, that also didn't work.

Comment: What about clear the cache of IE and try again? Do you mean all the jpeg images can't show or some of them in a specific folder can't show? You could compare the formats of the images to see if there's any difference between them such as if the image is saved as CMYK or RGB mode. It's hard to debug with only the description of the issue. It could be better if you share a simple sample or detailed steps to reproduce the issue.

Comment: When I try to load the image exclusively, there i'm getting cross mark on IE. When i checked in dev tools, there was one error as " Unable to decode image at URL". Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You could try the solution in [this thread](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192742/some-images-are-not-displayed-in-ie). The op has the same issue as yours and figured out it's a MIME type (or Content Type) configuration issue. Besides, here's [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33676982/internet-explorer-dom7009-unable-to-decode-image-at-url-url) you could refer to.