# JPEG Images not loading in IE11 browser through apache web server

Tags: apache, internet-explorer-11

I'm using apacher web server to stre the static content (like images, css etc.) with my website. Below is my apache configurations set as below :

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on
   <FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf|html)$">
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 30 minutes"
   </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch ".+\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf|html|woff)$">
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Please note that the same apache configuration is working in test region, but not working in prod region for same jpeg images.

The cache works well for woff,css, js,png files, but doesnt work for my few jpeg images which are loaded from specific folder for one of the website screen. Any idea why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this issue only occurred with IE 11 browser? Other browsers are loading the same images? Is there any error or warning message in the console of IE browser? Try to use developer tools and check the network tab that what is the status code for those images files and whether they are able to load successfully or not. It can help to find the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPEG Images not loading in IE11 browser served through apache web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57841422/jpeg-images-not-loading-in-ie11-browser-served-through-apache-web-server)

Comment: I've checked in dev tools, none of the jpeg images are not loading from one of the folder. I checked in fiddler also, those images are not all loading.

Comment: Is there any error message in the console or any warning message? Does other browsers are able to display the images?

Comment: @Deepak : There are no errors in the console. I've checked in chrome, its displaying properly without any issues. When i tried to open images exclusively like this : https://<applhome>/common/App_Theme/Green/images/Prev_disabled.jpg, then its showing cross mark.

Comment: Try to find the difference in the configuration or any setting in your test server and production server. check whether all settings are similar or not. check whether both machines are using same OS and updates. check and compare the settings for your apache web server may help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: @Deepak : There is no difference in the configuration file for Production and Test servers.

Comment: What about other things like OS, it's version. update version and IE version are all same as test server? Other thing i want to suggest you to do not create duplicate cases for the same issue. It makes us confuse.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT : I found one DOM error on the console as "Unable to decode image at URL". Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT : I found one DOM warning on the console as "Unable to decode image at URL". Another DOM warning is : The code on this page disabled back and forward caching for same image which is not showing on  GUI. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: BrowserMatch MSIE explorer Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff env=!explorer If you have this rule in your Appache server configuration than try to disable it for testing purpose to check whether it fix this issue or not. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934411/images-failing-to-load-in-ie-with-dom-7009-error-unable-to-decode-in-console

Answer (score 0):

In our application we have both gif and jpg images for the same set of images. I've both gif and jpg images in my local server. Hence I opened all the below gif images in MSPaint and stored it as .jpg.

Next_disabled.jpg
Next.jpg
Prev_disabled.jpg
Prev.jpg

Then I've deployed these images to apache where static content is present, followed by apache restart. Then the issue was resolved and the images are showing properly.