# IE Error DOM7009: Unable to decode image at URL

Tags: image, internet-explorer, csom, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-apps

I am working on **SharePoint 2013 apps** . In my app parts i have used few **images**. 
All the images are showing up properly in Mozilla and chrome but few of the images are not showing up in IE, i can only see the **broken image**.

Suppose i have my image at this location:

> 'https://365app.sharepoint.com/sites/developer/Spotlight_CommonIcon/Announcement.jpg'

So, this image is showing up properly in the Chrome and IE. But when i open it in IE It shows me broken image.
And following error is shown in the console.

> DOM7009: Unable to decode image at URL: 'https://365app.sharepoint.com/sites/developer/Spotlight_CommonIcon/Announcement.jpg'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Images failing to load in IE with DOM: 7009 error (unable to decode) in console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934411/images-failing-to-load-in-ie-with-dom-7009-error-unable-to-decode-in-console)

Comment: @Miguel-F Please stop thinking like this. I posted my issue. Why would i copy that post.?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that those images are CMYK JPG. Try changing it to RGB.
IE can't display CMYK JPG.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How can i check whether my image is CMYK JPG or not.?

Comment: I use Photoshop CS2. Open your image and then go to IMAGE> MODE. That will show the different colorspaces and a check will be in front of your colorspace of the picture you opened. Also in CS2 when you open the picture it tells you right at the top of the picture which colorspace that picture is using.

If you are on a mac, right click>get info and click "more info" should tell you the color space

Comment: Or you can download Irfanview.

Open the file, image menu, information.