# IHttpHandler over Https on IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, https, ihttphandler

I'm looking for your expertise/help figuring out why my http handler works perfectly over http and doesn't over https (only IE problem, other browsers work fine either way). I'm using the handler to display images and when https is used on IE, it shows some images and fails to show others images.

again, the problem is only happening on https and IE, all other mutations with other browsers work just fine. below is my code:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        Stream iStream = null;
        try
        {
            if (!context.Response.IsClientConnected || HttpContext.Current == null || HttpContext.Current.Session["GoodUser"] == null)
                return;

            var url = context.Request.QueryString[@"ID"];
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url))
                return;
            var fileUrl = EncryptionManager.DecryptUrl(url);
            if (!File.Exists(fileUrl))
                return;

            var buffer = new byte[4096];

            // Open the file.
            iStream = new FileStream(fileUrl, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

            // Total bytes to read:
            var dataToRead = iStream.Length;

            context.Response.AddHeader(@"Accept-Ranges", @"bytes");
            context.Response.AddHeader(@"Content-Length", dataToRead.ToString());
            context.Response.StatusCode= (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;

            var file = new FileInfo(fileUrl);
            context.Response.ContentType = MimeTypeMap.GetMimeType(file.Extension);
            context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            context.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
            context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.MinValue);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.Headers[@"Range"]))
            {
                var range = context.Request.Headers[@"Range"].Split('=', '-');
                var startbyte = int.Parse(range[1]);
                iStream.Seek(startbyte, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                context.Response.StatusCode = 206;
                context.Response.AddHeader(@"Content-Range", $@" bytes {startbyte}-{dataToRead - 1}/{dataToRead}");
            }

            while (dataToRead > 0)
            {
                iStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                if (context.Response.IsClientConnected)
                {
                    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    context.Response.Flush();
                    buffer = new byte[buffer.Length];
                    dataToRead = dataToRead - buffer.Length;
                }
                else
                {
                    dataToRead = -1;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            iStream?.Close();
            context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How long is the URL?  IE has a shorter limit than other browsers, and perhaps the extra S in http**s** is pushing it past the limit?

Comment: I really doubt it, simply because few images are loading just fine and others are not. It's also random, every time you refresh the page, some images will load, others won't. It's like the request is expiring randomly when you combine IE with https.

Comment: Anyone wanna take a shot at this? I would really appreciate your help! @JohnWu

Comment: We are going to need to narrow down the problem.  Can you use browser debugger tools to check the network traffic?  Are the requests for the images being sent?  What kind of response are you getting back?  Are they 500 errors, or timeouts, or something else?  Are the same requests showing up in your IIS logs or do they not appear?

Comment: @JohnWu, the only warning I see sometimes and it doesn't show for all files is:

DOM7009: Unable to decode image at URL: [link]('https://computer/site/proxy.ashx?ID=ge_1Kcuct43aDaaNy5i1MrjirRk0uGGrTVdIWJFy2dCq4a4v4XffkQezrl40h8-nMWIdj0LwIybNzVKdnvUxw0OEUUhNLf-h55sjrEtqyFTpurEoMXcehcVNVIz508q70').

everything else you mentioned has been checked and everything looks normal.

Comment: Check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934411/images-failing-to-load-in-ie-with-dom-7009-error-unable-to-decode-in-console) perhaps?

Comment: I did see that link before and it didn't help. I don't have nosniff option in my handler unless it's added automatically and I can't see it. Is there away to override/remove that option? I appreciate your help @JohnWu

Comment: You can check for the presence of the header in the network tools of your browser.  It may still be present-- bear in mind that .NET configs are [hierarchical](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx) and the offending setting may be in another config file, e.g. machine.config.