# Trying to display image in a different DIV tag when using mouseover

Tags: html

I have a drop down menu with a list of links. The list of links is in a  tag drop down menu and I am trying to display a diffferent image in a seperate  tag using a mouseover event. When the users cursor is over the text link a different image will appear in the picture location. Can I do this using CSS and not JavaScript? I am trying to code this so I can use it in other drop down menus so I need a way to code it where I dont have to do it using screen location like z positioning. I want the picture to display where it says no pic available which is in a different div tag than the list of links. This list of links and picture paths come from a database so it is created dynamically.

Example of code is:

```
<div>
<ul>
list of links...
</ul>
</div>

<div>
<img src="image location">
</div>
```

[Picture of dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sudDQ.jpg)

Comment: You will definitely need javascript for this.

Comment: The Images should be changes when you hover on links in <li> tag. is this what you want?? if yes it can be done via javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can try this way or it can be improvised as well. Hope it will help you

```js
/* jquery script */

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.linktag').mouseover(function(){
        var _datahref = $(this).attr('data-href');
        $('#targetdiv').attr('src', _datahref);
    });
});
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="linktag" href="javascript:void(0);" data-href="https://www.jobboardfinder.com/upload/1c7f578db0e8d9673c95dd5b1c7122c5a36081b0/logo_jobboard.png">link1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="linktag" href="javascript:void(0);" data-href="https://jessehouwing.net/content/images/size/w2000/2018/07/stackoverflow-1.png">link2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <img id="targetdiv" width="100" height="100" src="https://www.laxmipharma.net/img/product/No_Image_Available.jpg">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works but I am having an additional problem. I tested it using an image thats just  black txt on it and the script worked. When I used images that are in color that are bigger in file size they wont display. It shows a DOM7009: Unable to decode image at URL error. It does this in all the browsers. The script works with a small black and white image but gives this error with images that are bigger in byte size. I tried shrinking the images in byte size and it still gives this error and still wont display the image unless I just use the (small in byte size) black and white image. Any ideas?

Comment: or it may help you more 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934411/images-failing-to-load-in-ie-with-dom-7009-error-unable-to-decode-in-console

Comment: That script you posted works great when I use a small black and white image but when I grab images with color that are larger in file size it gives me this error.      DOM 7009: Unable to decode image at URL. The images are the same dimensions but just different in byte size.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I figured it out. Im such a moron lol. I was transferring .htaccess files to the server and changed my transfer to ASCII when I was FTP these files. I forgot to change it back to auto ASCII or BINARY and when uploading those images in ASCII that's what made them not work. I thought I would post this so someone else doesnt make the same mistake I did. Thanks for your help the script you posted works great.

Comment: @miff That's great. You can accept my answer. It will earn some rep points for you as well.