# How to load png images in internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I am not able to load png image in internet explorer. Getting "Internet Explorer DOM7009: Unable to decode image at URL:[https://test.com/img/cat.png"](https://test.com/img/cat.png%22) warning message.How to resolve this issue.I have searched in google but no one answer properly to get the solution.If anyone know please help to find solution.

CSS:

```
.bgr{
    background:url('https://test.com/img/cat.png');
}
```

HTML:

```
<body class="bgr"></div>
```

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of error may occur if you are trying to load a file that has an incorrect format. in this case, it looks like a png image. It can be possible that it is a different type of image or MIME type is mentioned incorrectly. If you had mentioned the MIME type then verify that it is correct. If possible for you then you can try to resave the image with the png extension and try to reload it. It should fix the issue.

If the image is hosted on a web server then as a workaround, you can send the new **X-Content-Type-Options** response header with the value **nosniff** will prevent Internet Explorer from MIME-sniffing a response away from the declared content-type.

You can also try to refer to the discussion on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934411/images-failing-to-load-in-ie-with-dom-7009-error-unable-to-decode-in-console) may give you some additional information that might help you to fix the issue.